# Pass value from one function to another

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to pass the value of fflag and refNumber to another button which is btn-send. I am currently making a modal. I wanted to pass the two values to send button. Please tell me how to do it. Thank you.

```
$('#inquire_t tbody').on('click','#msg',function(){
        var fflag = $(this).attr('name');
        var refNumber = $(this).attr('value');

        getUserName(refNumber);
        loadThreadMessage(refNumber, user);
        seenMessage(refNumber,user);
    }); //msg

     $('#btn-send').click(function(){

        });//btn-send
```

Comment: what do you mean by _pass the value to another button_?

Comment: Can you add HTML also please

Comment: Please elaborate on `to send button`, it's hard to tell what that means.

Comment: I have a modal for message thread, upon loading the thread it do get the value of fflag and refNumber. But when I clicki send the variable is undefines.I just wanted to acces the value of fflagg and refNumber inside  $('btn-send').

Answer (score 4):

The variables `fflag` and `refNumber` were local. To make them visible to other functions you can declare them outside. So they will be shared with the rest of the functions.

```
var fflag;
var refNumber;
$('#inquire_t tbody').on('click','#msg',function(){
  fflag = $(this).attr('name');
  refNumber = $(this).attr('value');

  getUserName(refNumber);
  loadThreadMessage(refNumber, user);
  seenMessage(refNumber,user);
}); //msg

$('#btn-send').click(function(){
  console.log("fflag="+fflag +" refNumber="+refNumber);
});//btn-send
```

Comment: It's better to also add an explanation rather than just code.

Comment: @JackBashford, I was in the middle of drafting the answer(of course along with explanation). Accidentally hit the submit button and you caught me there!